# Carriage return causes a visual space in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, html-rendering

A carriage return in my html code causes a visual space in the rendered html in Explorer 8.  I'm guessing this will affect other versions too.

For example:

```
<span>
(111)&nbsp;
222-
3333&nbsp;
444444
</span>
```

looks like this:

```
(111)  222- 3333  444444
```

There should be only 1 space after the first bracket, no space after the dash and only 1 space after the last 3.  I like the carriage returns for code readability, is it possible go keep then and still get the html to render properly in IE?

Here's the doctype information:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**Edit:**
I'm actually doing this in an ASP.NET MVC 2 app, and the aspx template markup is quite verbose which is why I've tried to seperate it into multiple lines:

```
<span>
(<%=((Model == null || Model.AreaCode == null) ? "" : Model.AreaCode).PadRight(3)%>)&nbsp;
<%=((Model == null || Model.Prefix == null) ? "" : Model.Prefix).PadRight(3)%>-
<%=((Model == null || Model.Suffix == null) ? "" : Model.Suffix).PadRight(4)%>&nbsp;
<%=(Model == null || Model.Extension == null) ? "" : Model.Extension%>
</span>
```

Comment: So you are saying that the effect is different from "(111)&nbsp; 222-
3333&nbsp; 444444"? Because a carriage return should be the same as a space.

Comment: @Joe Mabel I thought browsers weren't supposed to render the white space (carriage return at end of line)

Comment: They will render it exactly as they will render a space. And of course they render a space, otherwise when we write text it would all run together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scenario where `sprintf` type functions really shine. In the .NET world these are handled by `String.Format`. Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(VS.71).aspx) and you could rewrite the code something like this:

```
<span>
<%= String.Format("({0:###}) {1:###}-{2:####} {3}", Model.AreaCode, Model.Prefix, Model.Suffix, Model.Extension); %>
</span>
```

I'm a little rusty on the .NET string format syntax, so no guarantees on that code snippet. Here's another link:

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 2):

> in HTML, the Formfeed character
>   (U+000C) is treated as white space, in
>   XHTML

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_15

Also http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#uaconf (point 9):

> White space is handled according to
>   the following rules. The following
>   characters are defined in [XML] white
>   space characters:
>
> SPACE ( ) HORIZONTAL TABULATION
>   (	) CARRIAGE RETURN ()
>   LINE FEED (
> ) The XML processor
>   normalizes different systems' line end
>   codes into one single LINE FEED
>   character, that is passed up to the
>   application.
>
> The user agent must use the definition
>   from CSS for processing whitespace
>   characters [CSS2]. Note that the CSS2
>   recommendation does not explicitly
>   address the issue of whitespace
>   handling in non-Latin character sets.
>   This will be addressed in a future
>   version of CSS, at which time this
>   reference will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Not just in IE8. I've tested it with chrome and it gives the same result. First you need to remove the space from < span> < /span> element it self. and infact there are 2 spaces between (111) 222 and 3333 44444. So it seems that each carriage return is taking one blank space.

This is perfectly ok consider this HTML...

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is some static text
    with carriage return
    <span>
      (111)&nbsp;222- 3333&nbsp;444444
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

the output would be...

This is some static text with carriage return (111) 222- 3333 444444

Watch for the space between text and with in static text. So translating carriage return to space is seems like a general rule for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A newline is a space.

If you really want those things on separate lines, you could use HTML comments:

```
<span><!--
-->(111)&nbsp;<!--
-->222-<!--
-->3333&nbsp;<!--
-->444444<!--
--></span>
```

although that's not too great for readability either.  Personally I don't see what's unreadable putting it all on one line.  You could do:

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">(111) 222-3333 444444</span>
```

if you feel the `&nbsp;`s are making it unreadable.

Comment: I'm actually doing this in an asp.net MVC 2 app, so it's not the resulting markup that I'm concerned about, it's actually the aspx markup template.  Because the template markup is a lot more verbose, it's easier to read if I put it on seperate lines.