# HTML character spacing and spans

Tags: html, character, spacing

Why are the following 2 times of day not displayed the same and what can I do to make the second time look like the first?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
     8:00
                <span>8</span>
                <span>:</span>
                <span >00</span>
    </div>            

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the newlines between span tags. Like this:

```
<div>
 8:00
            <span>8</span><span>:</span><span >00</span>
</div>
```

I'm hard pressed to find it in the spec, but it appears that virtually all browsers take all white spaces and "compress" it down to a single space.

Here's a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965372/carriage-return-causes-a-visual-space-in-internet-exporer-8).

The accepted answer there recommends using `String.Format` to handle rendering more precisely -- this may help in your particular situation.

**Update:**

According the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.1):

> SGML (see [ISO8879], section 7.6.1)
>   specifies that a line break
>   immediately following a start tag must
>   be ignored, as must a line break
>   immediately before an end tag. This
>   applies to all HTML elements without
>   exception.

There's also an interesting write up describing this as a bug [here](http://www.42inc.com/~estephen/htmlner/whitespacebugs.html).

Comment: Thanks for the valid response. But this is actually some output on an aspx page where it is putting spans in for label controls. I guess I need to address that.

Comment: BTW: I solved my problem thanks to your answer. I put all the asp.net label tags on one line.